# Code igniter XSS clean and php $_POST

Tags: php, codeigniter

It is my understanding that php will urldecode `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` so I do NOT have to on my own

But it seems CI is rawurldecoding $_POST ($this->input->post()) because of global XSS filtering. I am fine with this; but I need the data to be urldecoded instead of RAWurldecoded. Meaning that I need to replace + with a space (' ')

1. Can I do a simple `str_replace` without causing issues?
2. Am I understanding what php does for $_GET and $_REQUEST? (According to the manual it says that)?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the XSS filtering by passing a parameter, if preferred.

```
$this->input->post('post_name', FALSE); // returns specified POST item without XSS filter
$this->input->post(NULL, FALSE); // returns all POST items without XSS filter
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Since I need the data stored as url decoded I ended up doing `urldecode($this->controller->input->post('ResponseOrigin', FALSE));` I am getting a response from a remote server that is url encoded that I post back to myself encoded and then I need to store decoded. I think your solution the best because I deal with the data raw. I